# How can I connect to my vps through Tor?

Tags: anonymity, whonix, ssh, vps

I need a static IP address, so I decided to rent a vps. Is there a way to establish SSH tunnel passing first through tor so anonymize my ISP IP? I’m using Whonix OS.

Answer (score 2):

All traffic issues from within Whonix-Workstation will either be routed through Tor or not routed at all. It's the very core of what Whonix is good for.

Comment: Then my ssh tunnel is encrypted and anonymous?

Comment: As encrypted as ssh and as anonymous as Tor.